# React native issue with special character

Tags: react-native

I creating an app in react native and using German language for labels.

I am using text "Passwort ändern" for "change password"; but when the screen is rendering all the special characters are changing into '?'.

Could you please help me out to render the special characters in react-native?

Thanks,
Saloni

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
 <Text>Password {'ä'}ndern</Text>
```